# Connected component as children type (TypeScript, ReactJS. React-redux)

Tags: typescript, react-redux

Have component Translate and Text, And want to define Translate as children for Text, but Translate have connection to the store and there is a problem (I don't understand why).

Translate component

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import appState from '../store/types/appState'

type TranslateProps = {
  translations?: string[]
  keyString: string
}

class Translate extends React.Component<TranslateProps, any> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.translateString(this.props.keyString)}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

  private translateString(key: string) {
    return this.props.translations[key] ? this.props.translations[key] : key
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: appState) => ({translations: state.translations})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Translate)
```

Text component

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Translate from './Translate'

type TextProps = {
  children: React.ReactElement<Translate> | React.ReactElement<Translate>[]
}

class Text extends React.Component<TextProps, any> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <StyledText>
        {this.props.children}
      </StyledText>
    )
  }
}

export default Text
```

And I have an compile error: TS2304 cannot find name 'Translate'

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "DOM"],
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "types": [
    "core-js",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "allowJs": true
}
```

Any component which not connected to store doesn't give this exception, any with always gives. Where is a problem?

Comment: Hi, Can you check if inside the Text Component "extends React.Component'<TextProps, any>'" is causing the problm. I suspect the type suffixed to React.Component is causing the problem. In your case those are not the props/type

Answer (score 0):

For the original `Translate` component class, `Translate` as a value refers to the class itself while `Translate` as a type refers to the instance type of the class.  In contrast, `connect` returns the new component class as a value, and the result of `connect` cannot be used as a type.  The default export obscures things a bit; to make the problem clearer, imagine you wrote:

```
const Translate2 = connect(mapStateToProps)(Translate);
type TextProps = {
  children: React.ReactElement<Translate2> | React.ReactElement<Translate2[]>;
}
```

Here `Translate2` is only a value, not a type.

If you really wanted the instance type of the connected component, you could use `InstanceType<typeof Translate>`.  However, the type argument to `React.ReactElement` is supposed to be the props type of the component (i.e., `TranslateProps`), not the component instance type.  So it would be more correct to import `TranslateProps` and use it in place of `Translate`.  However, there seems to be minimal benefit to declaring the type of the `children` prop at all (as opposed to relying on the default `ReactNode`) because:

1. You are not taking advantage of the type information in the implementation.
2. At call sites, all JSX elements are typed as `JSX.Element`, which extends `React.ReactElement<any>`, which is assignable to `React.ReactElement<T>` for any `T` regardless of the actual component type of the JSX element.  So you are getting checking that `children` is a JSX element or an array of JSX elements (as opposed to other kinds of `ReactNode`s such as strings), but you are not getting any checking that the component type is correct.

Thus, the best solution may be to just remove the declaration of `children` from `TextProps`.

Comment: I've try JSX.Element... Before TypeScript I used prop-types and like when I define childrens as exact component. Anyway, that's const Translate2 = connect(mapStateToProps)(Translate); not help. I'll try something else... Anyway, tnx a lot!

Comment: The `Translate2` example was just an attempt to illustrate the problem.  The solution I'm recommending is to replace `Translate` with `TranslateProps` (suitably imported) in the declaration of `children` or just remove the declaration of `children` entirely.